# merge/join disparate spreadsheets w/ some common values into one unified sheet

Tags: excel, join

I have five spreadsheets in Excell (*technically in LibreOffice Calc*), let's call them `A`, `B`, `C`,`D` & `E`.

One sheet, sheet `A`, has the column headers `submission #`,`member #`,`member name`,`comment`,`date`, & `time`.

`B` has the column headers `review #`,`field #`, & `score`.

`C` has `review #`, `field #`, & `text`.

`D` has `#`,`member #`,`member name`, `review from #`,`number`, `text`, `scores`, `reviewer first name`, `reviewer last name`, `reviewer email`, `reviewer person #`, `date`, `time`, & `attachment`.

`E` has `field #`, `field header`, `value`, & `explanation`

I want to try to synchronize these disparate sheets, it seems possible since `A`, `D` commonly share `member #`, `D` & `B` share `score`, `B` & `E` share `field #`, and likewise `E` & `C` share field number.

What would be the most effective way to go about this?

Can it be done right in Calc? Maybe using some VBA-esque syntax.

Comment: please give an example with actual data of your input and your expected output.

Comment: [this is a sample](https://github.com/smenglish/freestyle-scientist/blob/master/zerp.ods), I wan to merge two sheets like that

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect for the inputs, what is your expected output?

Comment: actually, more accurately [these inputs](https://github.com/smenglish/freestyle-scientist/blob/master/fusion_tables.ods) are what I need to work with, and the output would look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500115/merge-two-related-data-sets-by-common-value-libreoffice-excel-or-csv)

Comment: are you sure about your output? It is possible to do it, but you store your merged information in a form that makes it complicated to query. If you need no further treatment later on, fine, but think first about how you will exploit this merged data.

Comment: hmm, what way would you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89295/discussion-between-user3743222-and-s-matthew-english).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the excel VBA you need.

- USAGE

  Put on sheet A the columns of sheet D. For instance, let's treat column `review from #`. Put that formula in the cells : `=LookupCSVResults($B2,SheetD!$B$2:$B$xx,SheetD!D$2:D$xx,)`

  You should be able to copy that formula right and down and get all your values. All values in `sheetD` with the same `member #` are concatenated in one cell, with a new line separator.
  If you want another separator modify the VBA code and change `Chr(10)` by the character code of your choice.

I believe this format make it easier to reuse the data later on if necessary.

- EXAMPLE
  [image]
- CODE

`

```
Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String
Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
Dim r As Long   'Row
Dim c As Long   'Column
Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

s = strDelimiter
For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
        If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
            'I know it's weird to use offset but it works even if the two ranges
            'are of different sizes and it's the same way that SUMIF works
            sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
            If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, Chr(10))

LookupCSVResults = s 'Return the function

End Function
```