# Merge two related data sets by common value, LibreOffice/Excel or CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, join, merge

I have two datasets, they are stored separately but they are related, they describe the same phenomenon, from different perspectives, in different ways.

The encoding is not really consequential, here they are rendered as Excel/LibreOffice but I can also get them as CSV.

One "sheet", `Sheet I`, looks like this:

[image]

and `Sheet II`:

[image]

Using the field `submission #` as the unifier I want to create a single sheet which will associate the related blue fields to the corresponding pink field.

For example, the final result should look like this:

[image]

[Here is a link to those toy examples.](https://github.com/smenglish/freestyle-scientist/blob/master/zerp.ods)

Comment: What have you tried?  It would seem this could be solved with a simple `VLOOKUP`, or maybe one of the Consolidation methods outlined in HELP

Comment: I've been trying reading up on `VLOOKUP` and I keep testing it out with [these sheets](https://github.com/smenglish/freestyle-scientist/blob/master/fusion_tables.ods) but I've still not been able to render a table like I put in the question. I'm getting very distraught, if you're familiar with the syntax, perhaps you wouldnt mind giving it a try and helping me see what the correct syntax would look like

Comment: I don't see on your sheets or in your post anything demonstrating what you have tried, or what errors have resulted.

Comment: I've been trying the function generating button from the dashboard, also the answer of @Balinti, and also some tutorials but I keep getting some kind of `Error 502` as the result

Answer (score 0):

On sheet1 cell `h2` insert:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$A:$F,COLUMN(h2)-6,0)
```

The $ fixes the data table and the row for the lookup.
You can drag the function with the black plus sign which appears when you are pointing the right bottom of the cell.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, what does the B refer to? do you have a link to some documentation about this?

Comment: First, I hope this working well. is it? just type vlookup excel on google

Comment: I've been trying this whole time, but I keep getting errors. perhaps you might be willing to try it out with [these sheets](https://github.com/smenglish/freestyle-scientist/blob/master/fusion_tables.ods) and see if that syntax works

Comment: OK, few remarks: a. You have to put the purple data in a sheet name Sheet1 and the pink in a sheet name Sheet2. B. On both sheets, the first row (1) will be the header C. now I can understand that the purple doc is not unique by submission and the pink one is. Therefore, I recommend adding additional column to the purple sheet (Sheet1). C. on Sheet1 within cell g2 enter =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$F,COLUMN(H2)-6,0) D. drag the cursor as I described before.

Comment: but `G2` on the purple sheet (`Sheet 1`) is occupied by `time`, I put it over in `J2` but the result was `#NAME?`

Comment: Then you can just populate the cells by double click. If you will do it the opposite, you will get the first event found by submission.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean by opposite, what I'd like to do is associate the related instances of the purple sheet with their corresponding associate from the pink sheet or vice versa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89291/discussion-between-balinti-and-s-matthew-english).